# Pegar data formatada em HTML5

Tags: angularjs, html5

tenho o seguinte cenário.
Uma form com dois campos de data
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando clico em pesquisar, os dados estão nesse formato
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer para que eu pegue a data no formato "aaaa-mm-dd" ou "dd-mm-aaaa"? Sem esse dados adicionais (Thu Oct, 00:00:00 GMT-0300), alguém sabe?

Segue meu HTML

```
form name="relatorioPorPeriodo" class="formRelatorio">
    <input class="form-control dataini" type="date" name="data_ini" ng-model="relatorio.dataini" required>
    <input class="form-control datafim" type="date" name="data_fim" ng-model="relatorio.datafim" required>
    <a class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="relatorioPorPeriodo.$invalid" ng-click="pesquisaPorPeriodo(relatorio)">Pesquisar</a>
</form>
```

Controller

```
app.controller("RelatorioPorPeriodoCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', 'moment', function ($scope, $http, $window, $rootScope, $routeParams, moment) {

$scope.idempresa = $rootScope.idempresa = localStorage.getItem('idempresa');
$scope.empresa = $rootScope.empresa = localStorage.getItem('empresa');
$scope.usuario = $rootScope.usuario = localStorage.getItem('usuario');
$scope.idusuario = $rootScope.idusuario = localStorage.getItem('idusuario');

$scope.pesquisaPorPeriodo = function(relatorio){
    console.log(relatorio);
}
}]);
```

Comment: Aconselho a utilizar a library Moment,js (https://momentjs.com/) para lidar com formatos de datas, contagens de intervalos de tempo, etc. Utilize a função ´moment().format(")´.

Comment: Sim, conheço, mas não sei como usar, pois no exemplo dado tenho que colocar a data na mão.

Comment: Como instalo ele pra usar com angular? Não dá pra instalar com npm? Ou baixar?

Comment: Package npm para Angular: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando a library moment.js (https://momentjs.com/);

```
var dataInicio = "Thu Oct 01 2015, 00:00:00 GMT-0300";
var dataInicioFormatada = moment(dataInicio).format('DD-MM-YYYY');

console.log(dataInicioFormatada);
```

Package npm para Angular: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-moment

Comment: Já importei o moment.js na index.html
Agora como coloco ele na controller?

Comment: Sim, coloquei isso:
ngular.module('fooApp')
    .controller('FooCtrl', ['$scope', 'moment', function ($scope, moment)

Mas dá pau.

Comment: Postei o meu controller na descrição.

Comment: Instalei o via CDNJS e tb não adiantou.
Podes me mostrar como fica meu controller?